# Pull Non-App-Specific Config From Spring Cloud Config via Eureka Config Discovery

Tags: java, spring, log4j2, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-config

I have a Spring Cloud Config server for configuration, a Eureka server for service discovery, and two app servers (App A and App B).

I'm trying to share a logging configuration (log4j2) between App A and App B by utilizing Spring Cloud Config for serving the configuration file.  I can make the config file available from the server (http://localhost:1234/log4j2/default/config/log4j2.properties).

If I hardcode that value in my application configs (also served by my config server) then my applications can read the log4j config and everything works.  However, I don't want to put the absolute URL of the config server in my application configuration file, as the config server information should be provided by the Eureka discovery server.

Sort of a chicken/egg problem.  Does anybody have a method for resolving this?

Comment: Your Config Server can deliver that properties for all of you Apps. What exactly not work?

Comment: The issue is that the config server is located via Eureka discovery, i.e., it shouldn't have to tell other apps where it is and shouldn't need to be hard-coded on the clients either.  Ideally the discovery service would reveal the location of the config server and make it available somehow.